# run matlab code from linux terminal and display the desired output

Tags: linux, matlab, terminal

I'm running a simple matlab code via linux terminal with the following command:

```
% matlab_example_file.m

a = 5;
b = a*a;
c = a*a*a;
d = sqrt(a);
fprintf('%4u square equals %4u \r', a, b)
fprintf('%4u cube equals %4u \r', a, c)
fprintf('The square root of %2u is %6.4f \r', a, d)
```

```
matlab2021a -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "run('/path/to/matlab_file/matlab_example_file.m');exit;"
```

However, the output in the terminal disappears once the matlab code is executed. Also I only get the last `fprintf` output on terminal no the entire outputs as expected from the script (which is not the case if I use the matlab GUI).

Can someone comment what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe that MATLAB called like this opens MATLAB's command line interface, and prints there, not on your cmd. So, as you `exit()` MATLAB after the code, you close the command line interface. Don't exit.

Comment: @AnderBiguri not really, as removing `exit` takes me to the Matlab's CLI

Comment: But the printing happens in MATLAB CLI, doesn't it?

Comment: I only get the ouput for `fprintf('The square root of %2u is %6.4f \r', a, d)`

Comment: Use the `-batch` option to run MATLAB in the command window. You won’t need any other options, and won’t need the `run` call nor the `exit` call. Just `matlab2021a -batch /path/to/matlab_file/matlab_example_file.m`. — This doesn’t fix your issue, it’s not an answer, but it will simplify your life. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a Mac-vs-*nix text format thing.

It works if you replace all `\r` with `\n`.

```
a = 5;
b = a*a;
c = a*a*a;
d = sqrt(a);
fprintf('%4u square equals %4u \n', a, b)
fprintf('%4u cube equals %4u \n', a, c)
fprintf('The square root of %2u is %6.4f \n', a, d)
```

My 'educated' guess is that `\r` on unix means *return*, which put insert point for the output to the head of line. Without `\n` as *newline*, the new outputs just override the previous ones on the same line. That could explain why you can see and only see the last output.